# Pushing FileReader result in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filereader

I am trying to push the results of my `FileReader` in an array when clicking on a button. When I try to log the array, I can see that only one item gets added, I am not able to access the item by `[x]`.

I have a hard time storing the content of files (`reader.result`) in variables.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
const inputFile = document.getElementById('input-file');
let games = [];
$('#btn-push').click(() => {
        let file = inputFile.files[0];
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onload = () => {
            games.push(reader.result);
        };

        console.log(games); // Logs array.
        console.log(games[0]); // Logs undefined.
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="input-file" class="d-none" type="file">
<button id="btn-push">PUSH</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the filereader is [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing). It means that the onload will be called later and all codes that comes after will execute before the load event fires.

Either you have to put all your logic inside the onload event or call some function after the load event executes.

The alternative is to make your click event asynchronous too with a serie of promise + async/await:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  const inputFile = document.getElementById('input-file')
  const games = []

  $('#btn-push').click(async() => {
    const file = inputFile.files[0]

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text#Browser_compatibility
    // const text = await file.text() 

    const text = await new Response(file).text()

    games.push(text)
    console.log(games) // Logs array.
  })
})
```

```html
<input id="input-file" class="d-none" type="file">
<button id="btn-push">PUSH</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js" integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```